# wp_send_json does not continue with the code that follows from php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

In the following code, I call a javascript file with the help of wp_send_json, which does its job well, but once it finishes, the missing php code no longer continues, please help:

```php
if (isset($this->acsUrl)) {
    error_log('entro ');
    wp_enqueue_script('netpay3ds-confirm');
    $messages .= "<script src='../../wordpress/wp-content/plugins/netpay-checkout/assets/javascripts/netpay3ds-confirm.js' type='text/javascript'>
    </script>
    <script>
        Cardinal.OneConnect.start('{$this->status}', '{$this->responseCode}', '{$this->acsUrl}', '{$this->paReq}', '{$this->authenticationTransactionID}');
        console.log('sleep');
        </script>";
    wp_send_json( array( 'messages' => $messages ) );
    error_log('salio del js');
};

$netpay_card_processor_transaction_id = isset( $_POST['netpay_card_processor_transaction_id'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['netpay_card_processor_transaction_id'] ) : '';
$netpay_status_3ds_id = isset( $_POST['netpay_status_3ds_id'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['netpay_status_3ds_id'] ) : '';
error_log($netpay_card_processor_transaction_id);
error_log($netpay_status_3ds_id);`
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/: _"$response - mixed - Required - Variable (usually an array or object) to encode as JSON, then print **and die**."_

Comment: @CBroe use that since the way I send it I can send data to a javascript file and execute the process I need, will you know any other way to do that without the code dying in the attempt, thank you very much.

Comment: Why should it _not_ die after this? Sending more output to the client after this, would make no sense - that would simply _invalidate_ the data the client receives, it won't be able to parse the JSON any more. And if you still need to _do_ other stuff (other than producing output) after this - then you should restructure the code, so that wp_send_json calls comes later.

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately from the javascript I get a value to conclude the transaction, that's why I send it to that level of the code

Comment: @CBroe Taking advantage of his extensive knowledge, the reason for this is that I need to send some php variables to a javascript, said script uses those properties and returns a value that I use in the previous php file to conclude the transaction, the process must be synchronous since the script opens a modal from a third-party library and php should not exit until it finishes, this library is cardinal.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is how `wp_send_json` function was defined in WordPress and if you check toward the end of the code you see where WP kills the script if it is an ajax request or not by calling wp_die() and die respectively.

That is to say, any code below `wp_send_json()` will not execute.

```
function wp_send_json( $response, $status_code = null, $options = 0 ) {
    if ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) {
        _doing_it_wrong(
            __FUNCTION__,
            sprintf(
                /* translators: 1: WP_REST_Response, 2: WP_Error */
                __( 'Return a %1$s or %2$s object from your callback when using the REST API.' ),
                'WP_REST_Response',
                'WP_Error'
            ),
            '5.5.0'
        );
    }

    if ( ! headers_sent() ) {
        header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
        if ( null !== $status_code ) {
            status_header( $status_code );
        }
    }

    echo wp_json_encode( $response, $options );

    if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        wp_die(
            '',
            '',
            array(
                'response' => null,
            )
        );
    } else {
        die;
    }
}
```

To replicate what wp_send_json does without killing the script, you wil have to use php function to replace it like so

```
echo( json_encode( array( 'messages' => $messages )) );
```

Comment: use that since the way I send it I can send data to a javascript file and execute the process I need, will you know any other way to do that without the code dying in the attempt, thank you very much.

Comment: Put every code you want to execute before `wp_send_json` that way all code is executed before the script dies

Comment: unfortunately from the javascript I get a value to conclude the transaction, that's why I send it to that level of the code

Comment: From the code you posted, the codes below `wp_send_json` are logging errors or so. It assumes by WP that for you to send a message back to your JS script that means you are done with executing that script

Comment: You can explore https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action where you can use `wp_ajax_{$action}` action

Comment: Taking advantage of his extensive knowledge, the reason for this is that I need to send some php variables to a javascript, said script uses those properties and returns a value that I use in the previous php file to conclude the transaction, the process must be synchronous since the script opens a modal from a third-party library and php should not exit until it finishes, this library is cardinal.

Comment: To replicate what `wp_send_json` does without killing the script, you wil have to use php function to replace it  like so `echo( json_encode( array( 'messages' => $messages )) );`

Comment: try ur example send this on console: Fixed malformed JSON. Original:

Comment: set your debug to true like so: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your config.php to get the proper error message